# Why doesn't `static_pointer_cast` work with ADL, but requires explicit `std::`?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, argument-dependent-lookup, unqualified-name

Consider

```
// https://godbolt.org/z/z5M9b9jzx
#include <memory>
#include <cassert>

struct B {};
struct D : B {};

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<B> b = std::make_shared<D>();
    auto d = static_pointer_cast<D>(b);
    assert(d);
}
```

I'd've expected the unqualified call to `static_pointer_cast` to resolve to `std::static_pointer_cast`, because `b`, being a `std::shared_ptr`, should bring `namespace std` in using ADL.

Why doesn't it? I need to write `std::shared_pointer_cast` explicitly to make it work.

Comment: Until C++20, ADL works only with function call syntax, specifying a template argument explicitly, `<D>`, breaks ADL unless a compiler already knows that it's a template.

Comment: Consider the POV of the compiler: all it sees is `identifier <` which looks awfully like the beginning `x < 2`. So it's grammatically difficult  unlike `identifier (args)` which can only be a function call or an `operator()(args)` call if `identifier` designates an object or a "functional cast"/construction of a temporary [both are essentially the same concept through different syntactic constructs: `std::string("")` is a cast (explicit type conversion) but `std::string()` is not] if `identifier` designates a type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl

> Although a function call can be resolved through ADL even if ordinary lookup finds nothing, a function call to a function template with explicitly-specified template arguments requires that there is a declaration of the template found by ordinary lookup (otherwise, it is a syntax error to encounter an unknown name followed by a less-than character)
> (until C++20)

In C++20 mode your code compiles fine, demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/b13q4hs68